# How add npm Configuration file template to my Visual Studio

Tags: angular, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, configuration-files

Im doing a video tutorial to setup Angular 2 on VS 2017. During the setup process he search for "npm" and one template show. But in my VS doesn't. What I have to install to have those templates?

Of course I could just create "package.json" file myself but just wondering if I missing a package to do things easier.

[image]

This is my General Tab

[image]

Comment: Strange I see it. The only thing I have done is Resharper and NetCore 2.0 SDK. Not sure if it is NetCore 2.0. Do you have it installed? Have you installed the latest updates?

Comment: Also, do you have [General](https://imgur.com/DmK4Zc5) tab in Web?

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Yes, mine is exactly as the picture only in spanish. But doesnt found that template

Comment: How about gulp, bower?

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt I add a picture with my General Tab

Comment: I have 15.2 will download 15.4 and see if make any difference

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not seeing any Javascript tooling at all in your General tab, I think you are missing it.

I am not sure, which of the both settings are shipping it, but check, which one you are missing:

- ASP.NET Webdevelopment
- Platform independent .NET Core development

[image: Installer]

To do so, you need to start the installer:

[image: Installer]

Just a guess, but I think the important package is **Javascript and Typescript Support** in **Development Activities**:

[image: Javascript tools]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and, after much searching and testing many things, I found a solution.

It seems that in some cases the installation of Visual Studio is a mess and does not place the templates in the correct folder.

In my case I could find the templates in the folder

*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates*

and

*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates*

My installation of Visual Studio 2017 uses the path

*C:\Users\[myUser]\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ItemTemplates*

and

*C:\Users\[myUser]\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ProjectTemplates*

What you have to do is **replace the content of the first two folders inside the two second folders**.

And now it is possible to use the npm template and others that were also missing.